# Is there a keyboard shortcut for the therefore sign "∴" on mac? Or is there a way to create a keyboard shortcut for it?

Tags: mac, shortcut

The therefore sign "∴" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therefore_sign) is something I may need to use a lot. How can I get a keyboard shortcut for it?

Answer (score 1):

I found several answers for you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685146/how-do-you-do-the-therefore-%E2%88%B4-symbol-on-a-mac-or-in-textmate

a google search is all it took.

In the character viewer under math symbols. ∴

Comment: The last answer is the stack overflow  link is such a poor one it should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

For Apple apps, make a text replacement for it:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18439

Other apps like MS Word have their own system for this in their menus.

Answer (score -2):

period (then) OPT+H (then) period

OPT+H gives you the superscript dot: ˙

So you end up with .˙.

Comment: Not what s being requested, just a collection of dots that may look similar but will not  be searchable or match the real symbol for any serious purpose.

Comment: Point taken. If you need the actual symbol, for whatever reason, my solution won't get the job done.